# Transforming a sql table into its inverse

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, I have the following table with `State` & `City`:

```
CREATE TABLE #State_City
( 
    State VARCHAR(100),
    City VARCHAR(100)
) 

INSERT INTO #State_City (State, City)
VALUES ('PA', 'Philadelphia'),
       ('PA', 'Pittsburgh'),
       ('NJ', 'Trenton'),
       ('NY', 'Albany')


  State    City
  ----------------------
    PA     Philadelphia
    PA     Pittsburgh
    NJ     Trenton
    NY     Albany
```

I want to transform it into the following output where for every `State`, I want to return `Cities` that belong to different `States`(other than the one in the current row) in the original table.

```
State   City
----------------------
PA      Trenton
PA      Albany
NJ      Philadelphia
NJ      Pittsburgh
NJ      Albany
NY      Philadelphia
NY      Pittsburgh
NY      Trenton
```

For example, `Philadelphia` & `Pittsburgh` belong to PA in the first original table. `Trenton` and `Albany` don't belong to `PA` as they belong to `NJ` & `NY` respectively. Therefore, I want to return two cities that **don't** belong to `PA` in the first two rows. Similarly, `Philadelphia`, `Pittsburgh` & `Albany` belong to states other than `NJ` and that's why I am returning cities that **don't** belong to NJ in the output result. Finally, I am assigning the three cities that **don't** belong to NY(`Philadelphia`, `Pittsburgh` & `Trenton`) in the first table to NY in the output result.

I was trying to use a cursor to loop through the carrier list and use dynamic SQL, `NOT IN` & `UNION ALL` to accomplish the desired output to no avail.

Comment: Where does `PA - Albany` comes from ?

Comment: @Squirrel I added some more detail in light of your question.

Comment: What do you want to happen in cases such as (SC, Greenville), (NC, Greenville), (CA, Greenville) ... ?

Comment: @DancingFool In that case, SC,NC & CA all return 2 GreenVilles from the other states albeit end result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of a unusual requirement if these are the actual data.

Anyway, do a `SELF` `CROSS JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` on the same table and check for `State` not match

```
SELECT  DISTINCT sc1.State, sc2.City
FROM    #State_City sc1
        INNER JOIN #State_City sc2  on  sc1.State   <> sc2.State
ORDER BY sc1.State, sc2.City
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  SELECT DISTINCT
        SC2.[State],
        SC1.City 
  FROM 
        #State_City AS SC1
    INNER JOIN 
            #State_City AS SC2 ON SC1.[State] <> SC2.[State]
```